# Tracking of .py, .sh and .cmd files in Sourcetree

Tags: git

I am using git through Sourcetree to manage my files with my remote repo on Stash.
I have .py, .sh, .properties and .cmd files to my git managed directory locally but the do not appear in sourcetree to be staged or on Stash after making a push. I have edited my .gitignore file to accommodate these files but that is not doing the trick. I have even cloned the remote to a different path to make sure I am not crazy but the files are not in the repo. Please advise

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you have not run the `git add` command at all on your new files, since you never see your files staged, and you also do not see them on the remote after a `push`. `git` does not track files that are placed into directories it manages automatically. They are generally untracked until explicitly added.

To correct this, go into the directory (on the command line) and run the following command.

```
git add *.py *.sh *.properties *.cmd
```

While you're there anyways, you might as well also commit your changes.

```
git commit -m 'Initial commit'
```

Answer (score -1):

Problem has been resolved.I have come to a realization that the sub-directories of my local repo were also git repositories with their own .gitignore files and so on. I apologise. Thank you